# Using regex to find multiple matches between two strings

Tags: regex, pcre, between

Imagine I have a string like this:

`c x c x A c x c x c B c x c x`

And I want to find any "c" character that is between "A" and "B". So in this example I need to get 3 matches.

I know that I can use lookahead and lookbehind tokens. So I used this regex:

`(?<=A).*c.*(?=B)`

But it gets all the sting between A and B: `c x c x c` as one result.

And if I remove the `.*` parts, there will be no match at all.

I made an [example here](https://regex101.com/r/Vtw7W1/137). so you can see the results.

Comment: E.g. `(?:\G(?!^)|A)[^AB]*?\Kc(?=.*?B)`, see https://regex101.com/r/TeHHiF/1. If `A` and `B` are placeholders for multichar strings, use `(?:\G(?!^)|A)(?:(?!A).)*?\Kc(?=.*?B)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/TeHHiF/2))

Comment: Wow! @WiktorStribizew You are a magician! Thanks a lot. Please Send your comment as an answer so I can mark it as The Answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two common scenarios here: 1) the `A` and `B` are *different* single character strings, 2) `A` and `B` are *different* mutlicharacter strings.

**Scenario 1**

You may use negated character classes:

```cs
(?:\G(?!^)|A)[^AB]*?\Kc(?=[^AB]*B)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/TeHHiF/5). Details:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|A)` - `A` or end of the previous successful match
- `[^AB]*?` - any zero or more chars other than `A` and `B`, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far in the overall memory match buffer
- `c` - a `c` char/string
- `(?=[^AB]*B)`  - that must be followed with zero or more chars other than `A` and `B` and then `B` char immediately to the right of the current location.

**Scenario 2**

If `A` and `B` are placeholders for multichar strings, say, `ABC` and `BCE` and the `c` is some pattern like `c\d+` (to match `c` and one or more digits after it) use

```php
(?s)(?:\G(?!^)|ABC)(?:(?!ABC).)*?\Kc\d+(?=.*?BCE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TeHHiF/6). Details:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier that makes the regex engine match any char with `.`
- `(?:\G(?!^)|ABC)` - `ABC` or end of the previous successful match
- `(?:(?!ABC).)*?` - any char, 0 or more times, that does not start an `ABC` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `c\d+` - `c` and one or more digits
- `(?=.*?BCE)` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible, followed with `BCE`.

Comment: Excellent solution!
It seems we can use simple ``.*?`` instead of ``(?:(?!ABC).)*?`` since we have no concern about other possible ``ABC``'s between first ``ABC`` and ``c``.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much. But there is a small defect. If the string was `c x c x ABC c1 x c2 x c3 BCE c4 x c5 x BCE` the `c4` and `c5` also will be in the results. I changed the `(?:(?!ABC).)*?` part to `(?:(?!BCE).)*?` and problem solved. But still there will be another problem, that if we had this string: `ABC c0 x ABC c1 x c2 x c3 BCE c4 x c5 x BCE` the `c0` will be in results too. I couldn't figure this one out.

Comment: @MohsenHaeri Add both the delimiters to the tempering lookahead, `(?s)(?:\G(?!^)|ABC)(?:(?!ABC|BCE).)*?\Kc\d+(?=(?:(?!ABC).)*BCE)`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qHWqc8/1).