# Regex match capture group multiple times

Tags: regex

I'd like to have a regex capture all instances of a pattern between two delimiters.

Simplified example to one character patterns (goal: capture all `b` between first `x` and last `z`):

```
bbxabbcbacbedbzbb
    ^^ ^  ^  ^
```

should capture the 5 `b`s.

I tried `.*x.*(b).*z.*` which only captures the last `b`. ([rubular](https://rubular.com/r/r6ywV5nSDov9xy))

Comment: Had to reopen because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028292/using-regex-to-find-multiple-matches-between-two-strings) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651595/regex-match-especific-characters-between-2-strings) match between *closest* `x` and `z`, but in this current question, matches must occur between the first `x` and *last* `z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```rb
(?:x|(?<!\A)\G).*?\Kb(?=.*z)
```

See [regex proof](https://rubular.com/r/3j91cASg09pOTy).

**EXPLANATION**

```rb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    x                        'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \G                       where the last m//g left off
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator (omits matched text)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  b                        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except line breaks (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    z                        'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: FYI you are being discussed on Meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406320